# How does Pandas choose the reference category when calculating means for binary data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with famous titanic dataset where 1 represents "survived" and 0 represents "not survived." I want to calculate the % of people survived from each class.

Hence,  I run the following code:

```
pclass_survived = df.groupby('Pclass')['Survived'].mean() * 100
```

I get the following result:

```
Pclass
1    62.962963
2    47.282609
3    24.236253
```

My understanding is that Pandas treats binary values (0 and 1) equally as numbers and doesn't inherently know their meanings. So, it's not clear to me why Pandas provides data related to "survived" (1) but not for "not survived" (0) by default. I mean to say that if by default pandas calculate the result for binary (1) at first then if tomorrow the notations are flipped for example where 1 represents "not survived" and 0 represents "survived", then pandas will give us wrong information.

Could someone please clarify how Pandas chooses the reference category when calculating means for binary data?

Comment: `My understanding is that Pandas treats binary values (0 and 1) equally as numbers and doesn't inherently know their meanings` - exactly you are right.

Comment: Yeah I also think that. But how it by default gave priority to binary 1 here ?

Comment: I think reason is `True` is processing like `1`, so used `Survived=True=1`

Comment: Yeah that should be the case but then if this happened notations are flipped for example where 1 represents "not survived" and 0 represents "survived", then pandas will give us wrong information.

Comment: Exactly, but I guess it is not common. But possible.

Comment: Yes may be this is the case. Sometimes somethings are universally accepted to avoid any confusion. These concepts are not to be questioned as they may create a confusion. I guess the datasets and libraries  are designed in such a way that they understand each other.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, in this case, you should use a pivot table to remove any ambiguity. Here, an example with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Pclass'], df['Survived'], normalize='index').mul(100).round(2)

Survived      0      1
Pclass                
1         37.04  62.96
2         52.72  47.28
3         75.76  24.24
```

To give a meaning to your data:

```
>>> out.rename(columns={0: 'Dead', 1: 'Alive'})  # or {0: 'Alive', 1: 'Dead'}

Survived   Dead  Alive
Pclass                
1         37.04  62.96
2         52.72  47.28
3         75.76  24.24
```

Comment: This is a nice representation.  I am definitely going to add it to my code.